# Connect one computer with a single network interface to two networks

Tags: routing, networking

This is my situation:

Network A: 172.16.0.x

Network B: 192.168.0.x

Server X: needs to access (and be reachable from) both networks.

Members of Network A should not be able to see members of Network B. The two networks are in the same place, so they can be connected by a router or switch.
I know the ideal solution would be to put another network card in Server X, but in this case it is not possible.

Any suggestions ? What kind of equipment is required ?

Thank you

Comment: Why is it not possible to put in another NIC?

Comment: Are both networks on the same segment (ie. same physical wire)?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since putting another NIC into the server is not possible, what you can do is run a trunk down to the server, and add virtual interfaces so that you have both your VLANs setup on the server. Since you didn't specify what kind of server you are running I can't really give you much more instruction beyond the basic idea.

What you would need to accomplish this is:

- Managed Switch
- OS Support for VLANs

  - Any modern *nix distrobution
  - NIC driver support in a Window Enviroment (normally only found in "Server" class NICs)

Alternatively you could re-architect your network such that the server is on it's own vlan and you limit access via routing and/or firewall rules at the network layer.

Answer (score 0):

You want a router with static routes. Even a cheap one will do the job, any other solution means overthinking the issue.